# Python relative import weirdness

Tags: python, import

I have a file:

```
STARTDIR/module/submodule/config.py
```

I have another file:

```
STARDIR/utils/filesys/getAbsPath.py
```

Why does this line work, in `config.py`?

```
from ..utils.filesys import getAbsPath
```

It seems like `..` refers to `module`, not `STARTDIR`. There isn't any `utils` in `module` at all. In fact, doing

```
from .. import utils
```

yields

```
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

Comment: What is your python path? (import sys; print sys.path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
from ...utils.filesystem import getAbsPath
```

This is because:

- `from . import …` imports from `STARTDIR/module/submodule/`
- `from .. import …` imports from `STARTDIR/module/`
- `from ... import …` imports from `STARTDIR/`

Comment: it won't, since i'm starting my script in `STARTDIR` (so it would be beyond a toplevel module import error). but i've re-arranged my code to have that work.

Comment: What do you mean, “since I'm starting my script”? Like, because STARTDIR isn't a Python module?

Comment: yeah. the script i'm running is in `STARTDIR/run.py`. even if there is `STARTDIR/__init__.py`, `STARTDIR` won't be a module.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, as you've probably figured out, you can't use relative imports. Again, as you've probably figured out, the simplest thing to do is to add STARTDIR to your PYTHONPATH, then just `import utils.…`.