# Python relative import example code does not work

Tags: python, import

I have some example files laid out following the example given [in PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision).

`moduleX.py` contains:

```
from .moduleY import spam
from .moduleY import spam as ham
from . import moduleY
from ..subpackage1 import moduleY
from ..subpackage2.moduleZ import eggs
from ..moduleA import foo
from ...package import bar
from ...sys import path
```

When I try to run that file as a top-level module, I get an exception:

```
C:\package\subpackage1> python moduleX.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moduleX.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .moduleY import spam
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Why does this code not work? There are `__init__.py` files in each directory; shouldn't this make them work as packages?

Answer (score 24):

From the documentation:

- *[Guido’s Decision](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)*

you can see this:

> Relative imports use a module's **name** attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '**main**') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

By running it as `python moduleX.py`, you are doing exactly the above. Instead, try this:

```
python -m package.subpackage1.moduleX
```

This will import moduleX and put the top level at package. Run from the top of the hierarchy:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    subpackage2/
        __init__.py
        moduleZ.py
    moduleA.py
```

I.e., in your case from `c:\` directly:

```
cd c:\
python -m package.subpackage1.moduleX
```

Note one thing - the imports in `moduleX.py` are these:

```
from .moduleY import spam
from .moduleY import spam as ham
from . import moduleY
from ..subpackage1 import moduleY
from ..subpackage2.moduleZ import eggs
from ..moduleA import foo
from ...package import bar
from ...sys import path
```

The second to last:

```
from ...package import bar
```

requires the root folder (`c:\` in your case) to be a package (i.e. have `__init__.py`). Also, it requires bar variable defined in `package\__init__.py`, which is currently not there (so put `bar = 'bar!'` there for test). It also requires you to be one level up - so you have to put the `package` folder in another folder (so you end up with `c:\toppackage\package`) and run `c:\python -m toppackage.package.subpackage1.moduleX`.

For this line:

```
from ...sys import path
```

there's a note in the above PEP 328 link:

> Note that while that last case is legal, it is certainly discouraged ("insane" was the word Guido used).

See also other Stack Overflow questions about this that might help:

- [How can I do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)
- [An explanation for Python's relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports)
- [How to accomplish relative import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655526/how-to-accomplish-this-relative-import-in-python)
- [Python relative import weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126628/python-relative-import-weirdness)
- [Relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python)